# HTML Currency related

Tags: html

This is a general question first I will show you my code and tell you what I am trying to do

```
<select>
  <option value="doller">doller</option>
  <option value="pound">pound</option>
  <option value="euro">euro</option>
</select>

<h2>Caribbean holiday</h2>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<p>price</p>
<p>$200</p>
```

so it has a drop down list where user could select the currency type and the rest is the description and the price so what I want to do is when user selects the type of currency all I want to change is the currency and keep the rest same for example it show the price of Caribbean holiday is 200 Doller but if the user selects pound I just want the price change to pound. what is the best and efficient way to achieve this do I have to store it in database, can I just use JavaScript. Any idea would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with JavaScript, however if you want to save the selection when the page is reloaded you'll need to use cookies or some form of HTML5 storage.

You'll need to store and/or get the conversion rates like so:

```
var Conversions = {
    dollar: 1,
    pound: 0.64
    euro: 0.90  
}
```

You'll then need to apply a listener to that select to change the prices, and you'll need to make sure that all prices are wrapped in an element with the same class such as `.price`. Then you would need to write some code that would use this logic (Pseudo Code):

```
CurrencySelect.ClickListener {
    var Selected = this.value;
    var Rate = Conversions[Selected];
    LoopThroughAllPriceElements {
        var NewPrice = CurrentPrice/Text * Rate
        ThisPriceElementsText = NewPrice
    }
    FunctionToSaveSelectionToCookie(Rate);
}
LoadRateFrom(Cookie);
```

Comment: ahhhh i see I never done thing this way but if it works then it works. thank you for your help :)